# Check if user has selected any grid rows

Tags: jquery, mvvm, typescript, kendo-grid

I have the code below that will remove rows that a user has selected on a Kendo grid.

How would I check to see if user has NOT selected any rows (in order to display a message "Please select a row to remove") ?

```
// Set reference to the grid;
var grid = $("#employeeGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var rows = new Array();

$("#employeeGrid").find("input:checked").each(function () {
    rows.push($(this).closest('tr'));

    // set removed rows into a variable;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));

    // store dataItem in session Storage;
    sessionStorage.setItem('removeRecords', JSON.stringify(dataItem));
})

//remove rows;
rows.forEach(function (row) {
    grid.removeRow(row);
});
```